# Compare the values of two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table called `mainlinks` which has about six million rows. There's a column called `url` which holds url's from the web, and two more columns called `metaTitle` and `metaDesc` which are empty on most rows.

I have another table called `links1` which has about 3.5 million rows, with columns `URL`, `Utitle` and `metaDesc`. All the URL's in `links1` are also in `mainlinks`. `Links1` has several million url's which have titles and meta:descriptions in their `Utitle` and `metaDesc` columns. I'm now trying to get SQL to compare the two tables, and where-ever `links1` has a title and description for a URL, to copy that information to `metaTitle` and `metaDesc` in `mainlinks`.

I tried the following code:

```
UPDATE mainlinks
INNER JOIN links1 ON (mainlinks.URL = links1.URL)
SET mainlinks.metaTitle = links1.UTitle, mainlinks.metaDesc = links1.metaDesc
```

Phpmyadmin told me that several hundred records were updated, although I know for a fact that it should be several million. Just doing a quick browse through the two tables showed, for example, "https://zvelo.com" in both `URL` columns, but the values in the `Utitle` and `metaDesc` columns didn't get copied over to `mainlinks`. Any idea what the problem could be?

TIA!

EDIT: Could it maybe be that one of the URL columns has some whitespace after the actual url which the other one doesn't have, and that they are therefore seen as different? If yes, how could I get around this?

Comment: Is URL unique on both tables? Can there be a chance that redundant URL has two records in links1, where one record has data for the columns and the other record doesn't, so in that case, SQL has just update main with empty.... You can add a condition saying ´where links1. Desc not null´... so on...

Comment: @bonCodigo yes, they are unique...:-(

Comment: @Phil - According to < http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL/SQL-TRIM-Functions-23.aspx > MySql should have `TRIM` function that takes care of both leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @PM77-1 well, I retried the query with TRIM, and it's still busy working on it so far, so hopefully this will work!

Comment: Well, I changed the code to ON (trim(mainlinks.URL) = trim(links1.URL)) about an hour ago, and Phpmyadmin is still saying "loading", but when browsing the table I don't see that any more metaDesc's were added, so I'm not very positive. But I'll try to let Phpmyadmin/mysql do it's thing and we'll see...

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment try validating for empty column values...

```
SET mainlinks.metaTitle = links1.UTitle, mainlinks.metaDesc = links1.metaDesc
WHERE NOT links1.UTitle IS NULL AND NOT links1.metaDesc IS NULL
```

Comment: Oh I just saw your comment. That invalidate my answer. Can you check if URLs have white spaces when comparing?

Comment: I'd love to try, I'm just not sure how :-). Any ideas?

Comment: @Phil sorry we all live in different hemisphers of earth ;) I can see that you have gotten the answer to remove spaces `Trim` function. If you have an ID field for your `mainlinks` table, try doing segment by segment to see that your logic/syntax are actually working. Say for e.g. you may update ID from 1 to 1000. It's then much easier for you to validate as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the answer was to get rid of any newlines, tabs, etc in all columns. I used

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column, '\r', ''), '\n', ''), '\t', '');
```

Once I did this on the columns in both tables, everything synced up!